# CSV writerows after some rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV say 2.csv, posting the sample here:

```
,ANPIS,,,,,,,
,AGENTIA JUDETEANA PENTRU PLATI SI INSPECTIE SOCIALA TIMIS,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,Macheta Comparativa CREDITORI - numai pentru Beneficiile a caror Evidenta se tine si in Contabilitate si in aplicatia SAFIR,,,,,,,
,Situatie ANALITICA - NOMINAL la 30.06.2017,,,,,,,
,8. INDEMNIZATIE ART. 31 SI ART. 32 OUG 111/2010,,,,,,,
,Nr. Benef,Nume Prenume,CNP,Data Constituirii,Suma Contabilitate,Suma SAFIR,Differenta Suma,Explicatii daca exista diferente
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7=5-6,8
,1,IONELA,2820,Mai/2017,3579,3579,0,
,2,GHEORGHE,18609,Februarie/2017,185,185,0,
,3,GHEORGHE,186091,Martie/2017,185,185,0,
,4,GHEORGHE,18609,Aprilie/2017,185,185,0,
```

And I want to over-write using python 3 a list of lists to it **starting from 9-th row** and to keep first 8 rows as they are right now, I read that next() can skip header and I try like this:

```
import csv
with open("data//2.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = next(writer)
    writer.writerows(mylist)
```

But this will yeld:

> TypeError: '_csv.writer' object is not an iterator

How can I write mylist starting after 8-th row (in my case)? Thank you for your time!

EDIT: mylist will look like this:

```
mylist= [['AUGUSTIN', 14111, 'Mar 2016', 0, 600], ['AUGUSTIN', 1451, 'Feb 2015', 0, 600], ['IOAN', 1480, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 0, 291]]
```

and after write my output will look like this:

```
,ANPIS,,,,,,,
,AGENTIA JUDETEANA PENTRU PLATI SI INSPECTIE SOCIALA TIMIS,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,
,Macheta Comparativa CREDITORI - numai pentru Beneficiile a caror Evidenta se tine si in Contabilitate si in aplicatia SAFIR,,,,,,,
,Situatie ANALITICA - NOMINAL la 30.06.2017,,,,,,,
,8. INDEMNIZATIE ART. 31 SI ART. 32 OUG 111/2010,,,,,,,
,Nr. Benef,Nume Prenume,CNP,Data Constituirii,Suma Contabilitate,Suma SAFIR,Differenta Suma,Explicatii daca exista diferente
,1,2,3,4,5,6,7=5-6,8
,AUGUSTIN, 14111, Mar 2016, 0, 600,
,AUGUSTIN, 1451, Feb 2015, 0, 600,
,IOAN, 1480, Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014, 0, 291,
```

Comment: where is `mylist` defined?

Comment: I edit my post.

Comment: I also posted how my expected output should look like?

Comment: Why don't you write the header first in a file? Then open that same file in append mode and write the contents of your mylist in that same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv` files are not read-write. They're just ordinary text files mapped with an iterator, but only when using the `reader`, so `next` only works when reading.

So you have to read the first 8 lines, store them, then open another file (or that one again) in output this time, and store both the 8 header lines, then your new output.

This code does what I just described:

```
import csv
with open("input.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    start_of_list = [next(reader) for _ in range(8)]

mylist= [['AUGUSTIN', 14111, 'Mar 2016', 0, 600], ['AUGUSTIN', 1451, 'Feb 2015', 0, 600], ['IOAN', 1480, 'Aug 2014, Sept 2014, Oct 2014', 0, 291]]

with open("output.csv","w",newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(start_of_list)
    writer.writerows(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your question , 
First you read your file that is 2.csv and then you select your desired rows that is till that row data will be kept and then you open another new csv file  "desired.csv" in append mode and append both desired rows and your list.

```
with open('2.csv', "rb") as fd:
    reader = csv.reader(fd)
    desired_rows = [row for idx, row in enumerate(reader) if idx < 9]
    with open("desired.csv", "ab") as saved:
        writer = csv.writer(saved)
        writer.writerows(desired_rows)
        writer.writerows(mylist)
```

Hope this helps.